# Why am I getting this element null error?

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting this error, not really sure why. Please help, this is urgent.

UPDATE

```
if (flights.Count() >= 1)
        {
            int count = flights.Count();
            lblNumResults.Text = count.ToString();
            gvAvailableFlights.DataSource = flights;
            gvAvailableFlights.DataBind();
        }
```

> Server Error in '/WebSite3'
>   Application. Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: element Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   element
>
> Source Error:
>
> The source code that generated this
>   unhandled exception can only be shown
>   when compiled in debug mode. To enable
>   this, please follow one of the below
>   steps, then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the
>      error. Example:
>
>    <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true"
>      %>
>
> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the
>   configuration file of your
>   application:
>
> Note that this second technique will
>   cause all files within a given
>   application to be compiled in debug
>   mode. The first technique will cause
>   only that particular file to be
>   compiled in debug mode.
>
> Important: Running applications in
>   debug mode does incur a
>   memory/performance overhead. You
>   should make sure that an application
>   has debugging disabled before
>   deploying into production scenario.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: element]
>   System.Xml.Linq.XElement.op_Explicit(XElement
>   element) +116474
>   searchresult.b__1d(XElement
>   f) +64
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   +151    System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +201
>   searchresult.FillAvailableFlightsGridView()
>   +721    searchresult.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +37
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +74    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: 15 questions and you still haven't learnt how to format your posts?

Comment: You're gonna have to give us some actual code if you want any help.  Also note that posting a .NET error message and stack trace does NOT qualify as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have function called `FillAvailableFlightsGridView` and in that function you call `Count()` of some collection which is null.

Before calling the `Count()` check if it's null and in such case, assume zero length or do whatever handling you want.

For example:

```
int myCount = 0;
if (myCollection != null)
   myCount = myCollection.Count();
```

Edit: optimized code in your case would be:

```
int flightsCount = (flights == null) ? 0 : flights.Count();
if (flightsCount >= 1)
{
    lblNumResults.Text = flightsCount.ToString();
    gvAvailableFlights.DataSource = flights;
    gvAvailableFlights.DataBind();
}
```

No need to call `Count()` twice, as you saw it contains internal code that might be heavy.

Comment: is nonetheless correct, you are attempting to call `.Count()` on a null object, resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (flights.Count() >= 1)
        {
            int count = flights.Count();
            lblNumResults.Text = count.ToString();
            gvAvailableFlights.DataSource = flights;
            gvAvailableFlights.DataBind();
        }
```

To this:

```
 if (flights != null && flights.Count() >= 1)
    {
        lblNumResults.Text = (string)flights.Count();
        gvAvailableFlights.DataSource = flights;
        gvAvailableFlights.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: I have 2 XML files that I'm testing with, the older one (that contains less flights) seems to work and the new one doesn't. Oddly when I run the file with the old xml, the new flights show up in the dropdown.